# How do I create a set of numbers constituted equation in R?

Tags: r

Create set of numbers constituted by 0.03x^5 + x^2 + x + 3 equation. Assign the result to the "y" variable.

Comment: Your question is underspecified since you gave no idea what `x` values you are trying to use. Note that if `x` is *any* vector then the vector `0.03x^5 + x^2 + x + 3 ` would be the set of corresponding `y`-values.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1,100,1))
df$y <- 0.03*df$x^5 + df$x^2 + df$x + 3
```